# m-cycle as the product of distinct transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations

This is the problem 6.9 on I. Martin Isaacs book **Algebra: A Graduate Course**.

> Suppose that $g \in S_n$ is an $m$-cycle (i.e., $g = (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_m)$) and $g = t_1t_2\cdots t_k$, where the $t_i$ are transpositions. Show that $\{ t_i | 1 \le i \le k \}$ contains at least $m-1$ *different* permutations.

It's not hard to show that $k \ge m - 1$, and that's indeed a theorem mentioned in the book.

My idea is to use induction by noticing that $tgt = g^t$, and the conjugation of each transposition is also a transposition. This approach works for the case $k = m-1$, but I could not go further.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have $r\le m-2$ transpositions $t_i$
in $S_n$. Consider a graph
defined as follows. The vertex set is $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and there
is an edge from $a$ to $b$ iff $(a\,b)$ is one of the $t_i$.
This graph has $\le m-2$ edges, so each component has at most $m-1$ 
vertices. If $H$ is
the subgroup generated by the $t_i$ then each $t_i$ fixes each
component of the graph, and so $H$ does too. Therefore each
orbit of $H$ has size at most $m-1$, and so $H$
cannot contain an $m$-cycle.